# How to: Unlimited Bash/shell history?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to define an unlimited history in Bash ?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Add this to your `.bashrc` (Linux) or `.bash_profile` (MacOS):

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
```

There you go, unlimited history. Currently I have 27000 entries :)

From `man bash`:

> If `HISTFILESIZE` is not set, no truncation is performed.

That means `.bash_history` is never truncated

Also the same seems to apply to `HISTSIZE`, although I couldn't find that documented.

Another neat feature I'm going to try is this:

> If the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable is set, time stamps are written to the history file, marked with the history comment character, so they may be preserved across shell sessions, like the following:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "
```

Let me know if you have tried that already...

Comment: This does not actually work for many cases and bash history still gets truncated. See my answer below for a more complete solution.

Comment: Warning: this causes headaches with `gdb`; if you set an `HISTSIZE` variable it will take it as a 0, thus disabling history size entirely.

Comment: notes: you don't need ``export``, ``HISTFILESIZE`` is in number of lines (not bytes), and history file **truncating happens when you set variable** ``HISTFILESIZE`` (and when shell exits). So don't set it twice in your config file with different values...

Comment: @vaab: if I don't export HISTFILE, I can't see what my histfile is using "echo $HISTFILE" in subshells, so while it's not necessary, it can be helpful and does no harm that I can detect.

Comment: Does not work for me, my history is still truncated at 2000 entries.

Comment: Why not to use `unset` instead of exporting empty?

Comment: Would be easier to write: echo 'HISTFILESIZE=""' >> ~/.bashrc + echo 'HISTSIZE=""' >> ~/.bashrc + source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 66):

After many large, ugly iterations and weird edge cases over the years, I now have a concise section of [my .bashrc](https://github.com/fotinakis/bashrc/blob/master/init.sh#L35) dedicated to this.

First, you must comment out or **remove this section of your .bashrc** (default for Ubuntu). If you don't, then certain environments (like running `screen` sessions) will still truncate your history:

```
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
# HISTSIZE=1000
# HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

Second, **add this** to the bottom of your .bashrc:

```
# Eternal bash history.
# ---------------------
# Undocumented feature which sets the size to "unlimited".
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
# Change the file location because certain bash sessions truncate .bash_history file upon close.
# http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-truncated-to-500-lines-on-each-login
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
# Force prompt to write history after every command.
# http://superuser.com/questions/20900/bash-history-loss
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Note: every command is written immediately after it's run, so if you accidentally paste a password you cannot just "kill -9 %%" to avoid the history write, you'll need to remove it manually.

Also note that each bash session will load the full history file in memory, but even if your history file grows to 10MB (which will take a *long, long* time) you won't notice much of an effect on your bash startup time.

Comment: The history file gets truncated when you set ``HISTFILESIZE``, this is why you should remove any occurence of such event except the one you want. It'll be also truncated on shell exit (but that is expected). And you shouldn't need ``export``.

Comment: @vaab If you do not export, doing something like `bash --norc` will truncate the history again.

Comment: I use `export HISTFILE="/home/$USER/hist/\`uname -n``tty | tr '/' '-'\`"` to keep shell history separate per session (based on hostname and tty name).  Of course I have to create ~/hist directory first.

Comment: FYI, on my Fedora system, "~" doesn't work in HISTFILE; it doesn't get expanded.  No idea why; it works in other contexts.

Comment: Note you may want to check the value of PROMPT_COMMAND and not blindly append this repeatedly as it will do crazy things to your system. A null check or better yet a shell variable expansion search is probably safer.

Comment: @fotinakis Why are you doing `export HISTFILESIZE=` instead of `HISTFILESIZE=` when it is default in .bashrc? Don't all variables get inherited by subshells if `export` is not mentioned  ?

Comment: I use this to avoid the issue @dragon788 referred to: `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+${PROMPT_COMMAND} ;}history -a";`

Comment: I've used this for a while and I find that the "eternal" history file still gets truncated, albeit after a much longer time period. I still haven't tracked down why this is happening or under what conditions.

Comment: Question: why the `HISTTIMEFORMAT`? Removing it was the only way i could find of successfully copying my previous `.bash_history` over into the new one.

Answer (score 10):

Include in *~/.bashrc*:

```
# append a session's history on shell exit
shopt -s histappend
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
```

This answer satisfies the following criteria:

1. a separate master history (no session can interrupt your history)
2. automatic history writing (no hotkeys)
3. infrequent writes (no appending after each command)

### background

On interactive startup, if `$HISTFILESIZE` is set to a number, bash truncates `$HISTFILE` to that number. On interactive close, if the shell option `histappend` is set, bash appends `$HISTSIZE` lines to `$HISTFILE`, otherwise it overwrites `$HISTFILE`.

### tips for OSX (Terminal)

Every time a tab is created in Terminal, `~/.bash_profile` is read, which means bash doesn't go on to read your `~/.bashrc`. Add the following line to your `~/etc/bash_profile`:

```
# if bashrc has content, source it
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

### tips for screen

If you use screen, your configuration file is ~/.screenrc. If you want screen to record history, you just need to set it to use a login shell which will source your bash startup files (and record your history).

```
# use bash, make it a login shell
defshell -bash
```

Comment: setting `histappend` with apple terminal disables apples session history for the shell. The session history is very useful, doing what most people want -- restoring the history in the event of a crash or restart, and merging the history of mulitple sessions so new sessions start with the merged history of the past.

Answer (score 4):

A different concept (may not be applicable) but you can have `unlimited` history when using [shell-sink](http://shell-sink.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for may be late answer, but for completeness: at me (Debian Bullseye) works

```
HISTSIZE=-1 
HISTFILESIZE=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I never could get increased history to work on my Mac so I created my own.
I added this code to my `.zshrc`, pretty sure it would work in `.bashrc` as well. It captures every command you do and writes it to the file, with a line number.

It gives you a new command `hist` on the command line. You can pass it `hist -10` and it will show the last 10 lines of your new history file. Just `hist` will default to `20` lines.

```sh
history_file=~/Documents/history
precmd() {
    local last_command=$(history | tail -n 1 | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*[0-9]*[[:space:]]*//')
    local counter=1

    # If the file exists and is not empty, get the last number and increment it
    if [[ -s $history_file ]]; then
        counter=$(( $(tail -n 1 "$history_file" | awk '{print $1}') + 1 ))
    fi

    echo "$counter $last_command" >> "$history_file"
}

hist() {
    local num_lines=20  # default number of lines

    # Check if an argument is provided and it's a valid number
    if [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        num_lines=$1
    fi

    # Display the specified number of lines from the history file
    tail -n $num_lines "$history_file"
}
```