# Bash history limited to 1000 even with HISTSIZE=9999999

Tags: linux, bash, history

On my old notebook (Debian sid) I had this in my `~/.bashrc` and it used to work (e.g. history was more or less unlimited and it was being saved on each command):

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "lucio" "t470" "/home/lucio/virtualbit/progetti/workspace/vscode/teom/websi"'
export PS1='\[\e[1;31m\]\u\[\e[1;33m\]@\[\e[1;36m\]\h \[\e[1;33m\]\w \[\e[1;35m\]$ \[\e[0m\]'
export HISTFILESIZE=9999999
export HISTSIZE=9999999
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -a;printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}""
```

I copied over the same `~/.bashrc` on my new notebook (Debian sid like the old one) and verified it's being applied:

```
$ echo $HISTSIZE
9999999
```

but my history is being cut at 1000 entries. I also tried with `HISTSIZE=-1` in my `~/.bashrc` (based on [this](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/CHANGES#L3216) information) with same results: my history is being cut at 1000 lines, but I don't want unlimited history anyway, I want a very high limit, such as 9999999.

What am I doing wrong? Why it does not work anymore while it used to work on my old notebook? Maybe there was a package other than `bash` itself on my old notebook that made it work?

EDIT: this question has been marked as duplicate of [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/137438/how-to-unlimited-bash-shell-history),but please note it's not a dup. I already know how to have unlimited history in bash, except that solution DOESN'T work in my case and I don't want unlimited history anyway.

Comment: Is this your whole `.bashrc`? Are you sure there are no assignments to `HISTSIZE` later in the file?

Comment: As you can see in my question, I verified that HISTSIZE is 9999999 in my bash with `echo $HISTSIZE`. Anyway, I confirm those are the last lines of my `.bashrc`

Comment: Also for my Debian 11/bullseye system, the `HISTSIZE` is not really respected.
Looks like on reboot the history gets truncated to 1000.